# Trying to add IUSR user, finds multiple users

Tags: iis, iis-7

First time trying to do this, I need to give full access to a file to anonymous users in `IIS` 7.
So with some research looks like antonymous user is called `IUSR` 
So I came here to add the user to the list but why it finds multiple `IUSR` users? How would I know which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your search location is domain and not local machine. Change "From this location" field in above screenshot by clicking "Location" button in front of "From this location" and very first node should be your local machine (machine name). Select local machine and you should find just one IUSR.